# Track display of div and change display of another div accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the display of a div when display of another div inside tab layout changes.
div with id noshow should be hidden when tabs(id: tab-flyouts ) are open and vice-versa.

I have tried checking visibility of tab-flyouts and change the visibility of 'noshow' div accordingly but did not work.

```
<div class="tab-menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#t1">Tab 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#t2">Tab 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#t3">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-flyouts" id="tab-flyouts" style="display:none">
<div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid">
    <div id="t1" style="display:none">
        Tab 1 content
    </div>
    <div id="t2" style="display:none">
        Tab 2 content
    </div>
    <div id="t3" style="display:none">
        Tab 3 content
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="noshow">
This needs to be hidden when tabs are open
</div>
```

and here is jquery for tabs.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.tab-menu li > a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var $tabName = $(this).attr('href');
    var $tabFlyout = $('.tab-flyouts');
 $(this).toggleClass('active').closest('li').siblings().children('a').removeClass('active');

    if ($tabFlyout.is(':visible')){
        if ($this.hasClass('active')) {
            $('body').addClass('active-tab-menu');

            var $activeTab = $tabFlyout.find('div' + $tabName);
            $activeTab.siblings(':visible').fadeOut();
            $activeTab.fadeIn();
            var $h2s = $activeTab.find('.filters').siblings('h2');
            $h2s.each(function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                var $listOfLinks = $this.next('.list-of-links');
                if ($listOfLinks.is(':visible')) {
                    if (!$listOfLinks.children('li:visible').length) {
                        $this.hide();
                    } else {
                        $this.show();
                    }
                }
            });
            if (!$activeTab.find('h2:visible').length && !$activeTab.find('.no-results')) {
                $activeTab.find('.no-search-results').show();
            }
        } else{
            $('body').removeClass('active-tab-menu');

            $tabFlyout.slideUp(function () {
                $tabFlyout.children('.wrapper > div').hide();
            });
        }
    } else {
        $('body').addClass('active-tab-menu');

        var $activeTab = $tabFlyout.find('div' + $tabName);
        $activeTab.show().siblings().hide().end().end().slideDown('fast', function () {
            $('body').trigger('tab_flyout.open');
        });
    }
});
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ooXdLd

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the `noshow` DIV when ***all*** tabs are open, this is not possible based on your code because you are always showing one tab at time, and other tabs are hidden.

But, if you want to hide the `noshow` DIV when only ***one*** tab is open:

- Add a `$('noshow').show()` when tabs are hidden.
- And, add a `$('noshow').hide()` when any tab is shown.
- Or, Add `$('noshow').toggle()` to switch between them.